# CSS auto height dont work

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, and I want to make #left be the same height as #right, I have set height: 100%; but it only works if there is content.

the HTML & CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#left
{
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 100%px;
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#leftbottom
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
#right
{
    width: 800px;
    background: cyan;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <div id="leftbottom"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <h1>Content ipsum</h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <h2><- White space</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tested with position: absolute but it does not work either, how can I solve this?
also, I do not need to establish fixed height

Comment: % before px? really?

Answer (score 0):

If you put %, the words that can use the 100 of its size, not that it is of such size, if you want to assign size, use px

```
#left
{
    width: 200px;
    /*min-height: 100%px;*/ % before px? really?
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#right
{
    width: 800px;
    background: cyan;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: oops i wrote that wrong, but anyway if I put 100% left blank, and I want #left to occupy all the blank space (blue background)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    background: white;
}

#left
{
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
#right
{
    width: 800px;
    background: cyan;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <div id="leftbottom"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <h1>Content ipsum</h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <h2>White space</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution is not big for it. You need to use bootstrap column with equal height.

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
<div class="col-6">Hello</div>
<div class="col-6">World</div>
</div>
```

Know more read this
http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/